# SQL IN with AND

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE name IN ('abs', 'airbag_id', 'alarm')
```

This code make: 'abs' OR  'airbag_id' OR 'alarm'

I need to make: 'abs' AND 'airbag_id' AND 'alarm'

How can I do it with something like "IN".

I don't need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE name = 'abs' AND name = 'airbag_id' AND name = 'alarm'
```

...because I will use to many AND's.

Any idea?

Comment: What column exactly do you need from that table?

Comment: This makes no sense... how can the value of one column be equal to 3 different values?

Comment: And... how exactly do you expect a value to equal three different values?

Comment: Sidenote: Remove the quotes in `table` and replace with ticks.

Comment: GROUP BY thingy HAVING COUNT([DISTINCT] name) = 3;

Comment: I don't believe the problem is "too many AND's". The example query will return zero rows, because it's impossible for a row to satisfy the predicate `name = 'abs' AND name = 'alarm'`, we're guaranteed that at least one of those is going to be FALSE or NULL. I think you need to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Too many ANDs? What, are they rationed now?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a single column result having all these names. You can do it like this

```
SELECT some_column_you_group_by 
FROM your_table
WHERE name IN ('abs', 'airbag_id', 'alarm')
group by some_column_you_group_by 
having count(distinct name) = 3
```

Comment: The other users did the right thing - they asked for clarification, which you did NOT provide and then they downvoted and voted-to-close your question as unclear. The next time please stay put, answer to comments quickly and try to improve your question by editing it and providing example data and expected output. We don't want to guess what someone needs. We want well asked questions here that are useful for future visitors and not just you.